# How to efficiently merge two dictionaries in Python without duplicates?

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python project where I need to merge two dictionaries, but I want to ensure that there are no duplicate keys as the end result should contain unique keys with their corresponding values. Here's what I've tried:

```
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
dict2 = {'b': 3, 'c': 4}
```

```
merged_dict = {**dict1, **dict2}
```

This approach overwrites the value of duplicate keys, but I'm looking for a way to either prevent duplicates or handle them in a specific manner (e.g., by adding the values together or keeping the higher value).

I've searched for solutions, but most methods don't address handling duplicates in the way I need. Is there an efficient Pythonic way to merge dictionaries while managing duplicates according to custom logic?

Environment: Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: A dict structure **has no** duplicate key, that's its purpose, so you don't need a way to "ensure that there are no duplicate keys"

Comment: " adding the values together or keeping the higher value", both are different code, so what do yo want ? You can't need "some" solution, but a specific one

Comment: This boils down to defining an appropriate `merge` function to use with `result = {key: merge(d1, d2, key) for key in d1.keys() | d2.keys()}`. `merge` can return a value from one dict or another, or return both in a list, or add them, or .... It's up to you to define `merge` to produce the result you want.

Comment: For example, `d1 | d2` could be mimicked with `def merge(d1, d2, k): return d1.get(k, d2[k])`.

Comment: @azro - actually, the OP can need "some" solution. Look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78131120/10292330).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a longer way to do this than some of the ways listed in the comments but here is a way you can do it:

```
#The original dicts
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
dict2 = {'b': 3, 'c': 4}

#Create a list and a set for the keys.  The set will be used with union to get unique keys
dict1keys=list(dict1.keys())
dict2keys=list(dict2.keys())
dict1keysset=set(dict1keys)
dict2keysset=set(dict2keys)

#Concatenate the two lists of keys
concatekey=dict1keys+dict2keys

#Get lists of values from original dicts
dict1vals=list(dict1.values())
dict2vals=list(dict2.values())

#Add the keys and values to a dataframe
keyValDF=pd.DataFrame()
keyValDF['Key']=dict1keys+dict2keys
keyValDF['Vals']=dict1vals+dict2vals

#Get the key list with each key represented only once
NewKeylst=list(dict1keysset.union(dict2keysset))

#Group the data by key
NewDF=keyValDF.groupby('Key').sum().reset_index()

#Put the columns back into a new dict with sums for each key
NewDict= dict(zip(NewDF['Key'], NewDF['Vals']))


#This is the df that we build the dict from
display(NewDF)

#This is the new dict
print(NewDict)
```

The output will be:

[image]

If you want a max value instead of the sum just change 'sum' to 'max' and your output will be:

[image]

Comment: Great use of pandas for merging dictionaries and summing duplicates! It showcases inventive use of libraries for data manipulation. However, considering the added dependency, for simpler cases, exploring Python's built-in methods might be more efficient. Excellent for large datasets or within a pandas-heavy workflow, but for lighter tasks, simpler solutions could suffice. Impressive work, highlighting Python's versatility!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my variant of the solution:

```
def handle_duplicates(v1, v2):
    # Implement how would you like to deal with duplicates
    return [v1, v2]


def merge(d1: dict, d2: dict) -> dict:
    merged = d1 | d2
    for k in set(d1.keys()) & set(d2.keys()):
        merged[k] = handle_duplicates(d1[k], d2[k])

    return merged
```

By doing a `|` operation we get a "pre-merged" dict which has values from both `d1` and `d2`, with `d2` taking priority. Then, in the `for` loop, we find keys which are present in both of dictionaries by leveraging set intersection operation, and overwrite those keys with values in the way we want.

```
>> merge({"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3})
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': 2}
```

Or, if you would prefer a one-liner, here you go:

```
def merge(d1: dict, d2: dict) -> dict:
    return {
        k: handle_duplicates(d1[k], d2[k])
        if k in d1 and k in d2
        else d1.get(k) or d2.get(k)
        for k in set(d1.keys()) | set(d2.keys())
    }
```

But it looks huge, personally I would prefer the first option

Comment: Appreciating the initiative to tackle the problem first! Your solution using pandas creatively addresses merging dictionaries and managing duplicates by summing values. It's a testament to thinking outside the box and leveraging Python's powerful libraries. While pandas adds a dependency, your approach is particularly valuable for complex data tasks or within existing pandas workflows. Kudos for leading the way with an innovative and effective solution!

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't make it clear what you want to do with duplicates, here is a highly dynamic version that lets you do whatever you want. It doesn't change the original dictionaries, and you can merge an unlimited number of dictionaries in one call.

###### solution

```
from typing import Callable

def merge(oper:Callable, *args) -> dict:
    out = {}
    for d in filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, dict), args):
        for k,v in d.items():
            # None means this does not exist, ONLY create it
            if (x := out.get(k)) is None:
                out[k] = v
                continue
                
            out[k] = oper(x, v)
            
    return out
```

###### usage

```py
import operator

d1 = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
d2 = dict(b=1, c=2, d=3)
d3 = dict(c=1, d=2, e=3)

print(merge(operator.add, d1, d2, d3)) # add duplicates
print(merge(max, d1, d2, d3))          # max of duplicates
```

###### output

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 6, 'd': 5, 'e': 3}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 3, 'e': 3}
```

Since the solution can accept any function, you can even make up your own. This example will store duplicates in a list.

```py
from typing import Any

def store(a:Any, b:Any) -> list:
    if not isinstance(a, list):
       a = [a]
    
    a.append(b)
    return a
    
print(merge(store, d1, d2, d3)) #{'a': 1, 'b': [2, 1], 'c': [3, 2, 1], 'd': [3, 2], 'e': 3}
```

There is no requirement for the data to be numerical. The next 2 examples illustrate that you are pretty much only limited by your imagination with this solution.

###### string example

```py
dicts = (dict(a='h', b='w'),
         dict(a='e', b='o'),
         dict(a='l', b='r'),
         dict(a='l', b='l'),
         dict(a='o', b='d'))
            
print(merge('{}{}'.format, *dicts)) #{'a': 'hello', 'b': 'world'}
```

###### numpy example

```
import numpy as np
import operator

d1 = dict(a=np.array([1, 2, 3]), b=np.array([4, 5, 6]))
d2 = dict(a=np.array([7, 8, 9]), b=np.array([10, 11, 12]))

print(merge(operator.mul, d1, d2)) #{'a': array([ 7, 16, 27]), 'b': array([40, 55, 72])}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems straight forward enough.

```py
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
dict2 = {'b': 3, 'c': 4}

for key, value in dict2.items():
    dict1[key] = dict1.get(key, 0) + value

import json
print(json.dumps(dict1, indent=4))
```

giving you:

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 5,
    "c": 4
}
```